# Изменение числа в массиве (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord-api

Пишу команду для добавления монеток. Формат команды такой: "!команда @ник число".
В коде за вводимое число отвечает переменная "amt". Как записать переменную так, чтобы при вводе команды это число прибавлялось как ЧИСЛО, а не как текст?[image: Вот эта переменная]

[image: Вот это число]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всю ночь не спал, но всё же решил сам.

"amt" записал как
`var amt = messageArray[2];`

Вторая строчка выглядит как
`coins: Number(coins[cUser.id].coins) + Number(amt)`